# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to build a basic CRUD application in Spring Boot.

Made a Model class as below :

Employee.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String jobTitle;
    private String phone;
    private String imageUrl;
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String employeeCode;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getEmployeeCode() {
        return employeeCode;
    }

    public void setEmployeeCode(String employeeCode) {
        this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
    }

    public Employee(String name, String email, String jobTitle, String phone, String imageUrl, String employeeCode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", jobTitle=" + jobTitle + ", phone="
                + phone + ", imageUrl=" + imageUrl + ", employeeCode=" + employeeCode + "]";
    }

}
```

This is my application.properties file.

```
#MYSQL Configuration

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeemanager
spring.datasource.data-username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
debug= true
```

My Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sood1</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmployeeManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EmployeeManager</name>
    <description>Employee Manager App</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Below is the logs for the error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
```

I tried establishing connection in sql command line interface with same credentials and it's working fine.
Can anyone help why this issue is coming up and what's the walk around for this.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is mistake in your configurations
`spring.datasource.data-username=myusername` change it to `spring.datasource.username=myusername`

Comment: WoW. This resolved the issue.
Thank you so much Sir for the help.

Comment: If it's correct answer please mark this as right answer.